# How to autoincrement Prod_id based on Product_Name using trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

**Product_Details table** : (Fields) Prod_id(Primary key), Product_Name, Prefix and Slno(Auto incremented)

i need to increment **Prod_Id** based on the **product name** field and **prefix** field (Input will be given by user). i have  already concat prefix and id. but i cant achieve the sequence as i show below

```
    Product Name      Prefix      Prod_id
    BOOK              BO          BO_001
    FLOWER            FLOW        FLOW_001
    BOOK              BO          BO_002
    DESK              DE          DE_001
    DESK              DE          DE_002
    FLOWER            FLOW        FLOW_002
```

AS OF NOW I HAVE IMPLEMENTED A TRIGGER

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_INSERT
    BEFORE INSERT ON customer_details
    FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO product_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
        SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from product_details), 0) + 1;
         SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT((NEW.Prefix), LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
      END$$
DELIMITER;
```

But in this code i am getting output like book_001, flower_002,book_003, desk_004,Flower_005....so on.. i need a separate sequence for each product name. Help with a trigger code will be much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Acube.