# Need to convert date to word using trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

[image]I have created a datetoword function in Mysql. Checked the function working fine. Now using this function need to convert the date from field1 (date-datetype) to field2 (Varchar-datatype) within the table using trigger on before insert.

Tried with some trigger code

Set New.dobw = CALL date_to_words(New.dob);

Help needed in this regard.

Show function status;  (output is shown in screenshot)

SELECT date_to_words(NOW())
[image: SELECT date_to_words(NOW())]

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION date_to_words\G` and post the output.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why did you do this? DATEs should be stored as DATEs, VARCHARs as VARCHARS and so on.

Comment: i need  for my application the date field in date and in word format for printing in reports

Comment: cant post the full function, too long to post the output of the SHOW CREATE FUNCTION date_to_words\G

Comment: Here is a question: What exactly would the output of the `date_to_words` function produce ? For example, what would be the output of `SELECT date_to_words(NOW());` ?

Comment: Next question: Is the table for this trigger in the `mcet` database ?

Comment: @ RolandoMySQLDBA : yes the database is mcet, the output screenshot of SELECT date_to_words(NOW()); is posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [**your comment**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91274/need-to-convert-date-to-word-using-trigger#comment164248_91328), the trigger has multiple lines.

You need a `BEGIN...END` block as follows:

```
USE mcet
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_student_details_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER tg_student_details_insert BEFORE INSERT
ON student_details FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.created_date = NOW();
    SET NEW.dobw = date_to_words(NEW.dob);
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

You answered this question before ([How to autoincrement Prod_id based on Product_Name using trigger in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61094/how-to-autoincrement-prod-id-based-on-product-name-using-trigger-in-mysql/61148#61148)). In that post, you used a `BEGIN...END` block for four(4) lines of code. You needed one for this post as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Stored Function, remove the keyword "CALL".

If that does not suffice, please show us

```
SHOW CREATE TRIGGER ...
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
```

Comment: after removin CALL form the trigger also its not working.Set New.dobw = date_to_words(New.dob);

Comment: The whole TRIGGER and the whole table, please.  Plus any error message associated with "not working".

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER tg_student_details_insert  BEFORE INSERT ON student_details 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.created_date = NOW();
Set New.dobw = CALL date_to_words(New.dob);

I am getting a Syntax error.

Comment: You added back the "CALL"?  I assume the syntax error pointed either to 'CALL...' or 'date_to_words...', correct?

Comment: after removing CALL as i m getting the same error

Comment: Rick James, got any idea in this?

Comment: Please show us the entire error message.  Syntax error always points to where the error is, although sometimes it says "near ''", which implies it fell off the end expecting something else.